# Matrix representation of the qutrit gate analogous to Pauli-$X$ gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

What is the qutrit gate analogous to the $X$ gate for qubits, i.e. NOT gate? and what is the matrix representation of that gate?

I have searched on the Internet but couldn't find anything related.

Edit:

I would like to know the state matrix of the Controlled T-Shift gate if possible.

Comment: What would be the action of such a gate? A NOT gate for (qubit) systems makes perfect sense to me as it transforms $|0\rangle \to |1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle \to |0\rangle$. How is a NOT gate defined if you have three basis states $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle$?

Comment: I dont know honestly.I assumed that if there is a X Gate for qubits then there must be for qutrits as well.

Comment: If you scroll for a bit this blog post discusses the TShift gate which is the closest thing I can find to a Pauli X for qutrits -> https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_qutrits_bernstein_vazirani/

Comment: Look at the clock and shift matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices.
X is a shift in higher dimensions.

Comment: @DanyloY Hi!I am looking for the Controlled T-Shift gate not the T-Shift gate.

Comment: @RootGroves Please keep one post limited to one question. You can make another post looking for a matrix representation of Controlled-NOT for qutrits. This helps other people searching for the same question in future to find the answer faster.

Comment: @RootGroves This older post on controlled qutrit gates may be helpful to you https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/defining-standard-qubit-gates-for-qutrits

Comment: @Callum thanks a lot!But I have already seen it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on what I said in the comments it seems the closest thing to a Pauli $X$ or $\text{NOT}$ operation for qutrits is the so-called $\text{TShift}$ gate.

This gate has the following action on the computational basis states...

$$
\begin{align}
\text{TShift}|0 \rangle &= |1\rangle \\
\text{TShift}|1 \rangle &= |2\rangle \\
\text{TShift}|2 \rangle &= |0\rangle \\
\end{align}
$$

Recall that the basis states for a qutrit system are defined as the following unit vectors

\begin{equation}
|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\,, \quad |1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\,, \quad
|2\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

A qutrit is defined as a linear combination of these basis states

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle = \gamma |2\rangle\,, \quad |\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2 + |\gamma|^2 = 1
\end{equation}

You can see from the above that the $(3 \times 3)$ unitary matrix for this operation is the following

$$
\begin{equation}
\text{TShift} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
$$

This was new to me as well actually. Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in the matrix. It should be

$$\text{TShift} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}\,.$$

Because here,$ |1\rangle \mapsto |0\rangle$ and $|2\rangle \mapsto |2\rangle$.

Comment: Ah yes, you’re correct. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Qutrit gates equivalent to Pauli $X$ gate for qubit would be generalized Pauli $X$ gates for a $3$-level system.

The action of generalized Pauli $X$ for $n$-level on the basis states is given by

$$ X(x) |j\rangle = |x \oplus j \rangle \tag{1}\,,$$

where

- $\{|j\rangle\} \equiv \{|0\rangle, |1\rangle, \cdots, |n-1\rangle\} $ are the basis states of your system
- $x$ is the *shift* & $x\in\{0,1,\cdots n-1\} $
- $\oplus$ is the cyclic addition operator, meaning that the result of the addition is $(x +j) \text{mod} (n)\,.$

---

Hence, for qutrit, we have two gates. (Technically 3, but  $X(0)$ is trivial)

**Gate 1 :** $X(1)$

- $X(1)|0\rangle = |0\oplus1\rangle = |(0+1) \text{mod} (3)\rangle = |1\rangle$
- $X(1)|1\rangle = |1\oplus1\rangle = |(1 +1) \text{mod} (3)\rangle = |2\rangle$
- $X(1)|2\rangle = |2\oplus1\rangle = |(2+1) \text{mod} (3)\rangle = |0\rangle$

Hence, the gate is

$$X(1) = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}\,.$$

**Gate 2 :** $X(2)$

- $X(2)|0\rangle = |0\oplus2\rangle = |(0+2) \text{mod} (3)\rangle = |2\rangle$
- $X(2)|1\rangle = |1\oplus2\rangle = |(1+2) \text{mod} (3)\rangle = |0\rangle$
- $X(2)|2\rangle = |2\oplus2\rangle = |(2 +2) \text{mod} (3)\rangle = |1\rangle$

Hence, the gate is

$$X(2) = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0 \\0&0&1\\ 1&0&0  \end{bmatrix}\tag{3}\,.$$

Comment: Cool generalisation :) thats useful to know.

Comment: @Callum Thank you. You can also find generalized qudit $Z$-operators in [this comment of mine](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34634/how-to-create-a-maximally-entangled-state-of-two-4-level-quantum-mechanical-syst/34635#comment45903_34635)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: I think there's a minor typo in the last equation. It should be $X(2)$ rather than $X(1)$ right?

Comment: @Callum Oh yes. My bad. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The article [Elementary gates of ternary quantum logic circuit](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5485.pdf) defines three qutrit NOT gates:
\begin{split}
X^{(01)} &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
X^{(02)} &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
X^{(12)} &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
I found this reference while reading [Qudit Dicke state preparation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.04989.pdf), which also makes use of such qutrit NOT gates.