# CCTShift(1) gate for qutrits

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-control

What is the matrix for the CCTShift(1) gate? It has to be a $(27 \times 27)$ matrix.

Suppose we have two control qutrits and a single target qutrit.
If one control qutrit is found in state $|2\rangle$ and the other control qutrit is found in state $|1\rangle$ then how would the target qutrit change, would it be TShifted at all? Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of CCTShift? From whence did you get that term?

Comment: @Root Groves By $\text{TShift}(1)$ do you mean this ternary operation from a previous post? -> https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/matrix-representation-of-the-qutrit-gate-analogous-to-pauli-x-gate/35210#35210?
$$\text{TShift} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Also how are you defining the controls here? What state do the control qutrits need to be in for the ternary shift ($\text{TShift}$) to be applied to the target qutrit?

Comment: @Callum exactly.The CCTShift(1) gate for 3 qutrits is what is the CCNOT gate for a 3 qubits.

Comment: Seems the Toffoli gate isn't uniquely defined for qutrits. I think there are different conventions. See SECTION V of this paper -> https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5485.pdf